# Android number pick

Tags: android, numbers

I want to use this number pick https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/org.vernazza.androidfuel/ss-480-2-4 but I read that the numberpicker in android are compatibile with API level 11 but this application https://market.android.com/details?id=org.vernazza.androidfuel&feature=search_result is for api level 5+ and use the numberpicker...how ???

Answer (score 1):

There are some number picker widgets that were created before API 11 added one. This one is quite good: http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5